# why this deep first search, with a starting vertex of 3, go this way?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Please see the Depth-First Search execution (red line) in the following graph:

[image: Depth-First Search Execution]

My question: Why doesn't it process the node 1 first?

Comment: It could go either way, both executions would yield in correct spanning trees. It all depends on the graph's in memory representation and how the dfs was implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your algorithm was implemented. There isn't a "wrong" way or to perform dfs unless you want it to behave a certain way.